# stop parent page from scrolling down to iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have embedded a website using iframe.
Whenever the parent page loads, the embedded page makes the parent page scroll down to the iframe. I cannot change any code in the embedded page, only the parent page.
Here's the [fiddle of the issue][1]:

HTML:

```
<iframe src="http://store.ecwid.com/#!/~/cart" width="100%" height="100%" id="Container"></iframe>
```

CSS:

```
body { margin-top: 100px; height: 1000px; }
```

How can I prevent the parent page from scrolling down to the iframe?

**IMPORTANT UPDATE: ALMOST THERE**

So we've added the following javascript to force the page to scroll bacl to the top:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", runOnScroll);

function runOnScroll(){
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", runOnScroll);
}
```

It does work as you can see [in this fiddle][2]. However, on the iPad and iPhone, you can clearly see the page scolling back then up again. On the PC, you can't see the transition.
Please visit [this website][3] so you can check both transitions (pc and mobile).
I'd like to know if there is anything we can add to the code so:

1. the transition in mobile is not noticed like in the pc (*preferred choice*)

OR

2. the transition is smoother (slower scrolling or something like that)

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue reproduced in the fiddle. It's just an iframe at the top of the page

Comment: @Sanova yeah it does jump to the iframe position, the whole document gets shifted actually

Comment: The content you're loading is telling the whole document to scroll down. Unfortunately, since you can't change the code of the embedded page, you're stuck having to allow this behavior.

Comment: well I've seen codes to scroll the parent page up. Can't I do something like that once the whole iframe loads? @MarcoDelValle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I added a bit of JavaScript that listens to the first time the document is scrolled down. When the document is scrolled down for the first time, it'll force itself back to the top, then it'll remove the listener so that the user may scroll as desired afterward.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></link>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<iframe src="http://store4549118.ecwid.com/#!/~/cart" width="100%" height="100%" id="Container"></iframe>
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT** (In a file named scripts.js)

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", runOnScroll);

function runOnScroll(){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 0},1000);
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", runOnScroll);
}
```

Give it a shot, and let me know if it works!

Comment: I've updated the question. thanks, it does work but take a look at the question, there is one little thing left to see @marcodelvalle

Comment: To animate the scroll, it's easiest to use the JQuery library, so I added two lines of code to the answer above: First: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>` in the `<head>` to import the JQuery library. Second: changed the scroll to `$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 0},1000);` this is a JQuery command that tells the page to animate to the top in 1000 milliseconds.